# How to divide the web page in different segment.?

Tags: java, html, css

Hi Currently i am working in web project. There it self i am designing a website for mobile device. Here i want to know behalf of what i can use pixel for footer,header.And what is default height and width for mobile device.
Here some sample code is there

```
      <body>
      <div id="header">
      <h1>Books Gallery</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      **Copyright © 2016*
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try frameworks like `Bootstrap` which are designed to take care of all these, search for responsive design in Google.

Comment: Whatever the screen may be, height does n't matters. Always the width has to be adjusted as per the screen size. I suggest [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

These are the top-most Responsive Design CSS Frameworks, which provide this functionality, built-in:

1. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)
2. [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com)
3. [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com)
4. [Google Material Design Lite](http://getmdl.io)

Also, remember that this is not google. This is a website to help you out if your code is somehow not working and you cannot find a solution, or want someone else to look at your code and tell you the solution. But you gotta research on the problem and help yourself first.

I again state it: This is not google. For Search Queries like these, go to [Google.com](http://google.com)

Read about Media Queries Here: [Using Media Queries MDN](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZhO6Fq7rKAhXJA44KHQcUB0EQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FCSS%2FMedia_Queries%2FUsing_media_queries&usg=AFQjCNHC1tPH8ULrKMQciPdwo0UzCutUgw&sig2=sz9CG1n9VUy7qg4DfrpdYw&bvm=bv.112064104,d.c2E)

Media Queries basically means, you are modifying your website to make it usable on different devices.

All the above listed frameworks do that for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default width and height for mobile devices.

If you are looking for a perfect resizing for your website on mobile devices, check 'responsive' tools like Bootstrap.